# Django AttributeError: module 'cal.views' has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem to create a calendar with django, this code is similar a tutorial, but the problem is in folder cal/views
my code with django detects attribute errors and I no longer know what could be wrong, I already checked the files in the "cal" folder
pls help me in my code :(

this is the code in descubretepic/cal/views

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import *
from .utils import Calendar
```

```
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'cal/calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # use today's date for the calendar
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('day', None))

        # Instantiate our calendar class with today's year and date
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)

        # Call the formatmonth method, which returns our calendar as a table
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        return context

def get_date(req_day):
    if req_day:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_day.split('-'))
        return date(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.today()
```

my code in descubretepic/cal/urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'cal'
urlpatterns = [
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^calendar/$', views.CalendarView.as_view(), name='calendar'), # here
]
```

Comment: Please fix your question, urls.py code is the same as views.py, something went wrong. And please provide full traceback also

Comment: sorry, for the error, the code in cal/urls is fixed!

Comment: Could you show the error message? the full version of the message will be better to trace the error

Comment: this is the message error

`
 File "/home/y8/Escritorio/pruebas/prueba/cal/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
AttributeError: module 'cal.views' has no attribute 'index'
´

Answer (score 1):

There is an error because you're using `views.index` but inside your `views.py`, there is no `index` view. So you should implement it or you could remove it like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^calendar/$', views.CalendarView.as_view(), name='calendar'),
]
```